# MySQL query takes more time to fetch data [MySQL]

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, mysql-workbench, query-performance

I have `500000` records table in my `MySQL server`. When running a query it takes more time for query execution. sometimes it goes beyond a minute.

Below I have added my MySQL machine detail.

> RAM-16GB
>
> Processor : Intel(R) -Core™ i5-4460M CPU @3.20GHz
>
> OS: Windows  server 64 bit

I know there is no problem with my machine since it is a standalone machine and no other applications there.

Maybe the problem with my query. I have gone through the MySql site and found that I have used proper syntax. But I don't know exactly the reason for the delay in the result.

```
SELECT SUM(`samplesalesdata50000`.`UnitPrice`) AS `UnitPrice`, `samplesalesdata50000`.`SalesChannel` AS `Channel`
FROM `samplesalesdata50000` AS `samplesalesdata50000`
GROUP BY `samplesalesdata50000`.`SalesChannel`
ORDER BY 2 ASC
LIMIT 200  OFFSET 0
```

**Can anyone please let me know whether the duration, depends on the table or the query that I have used**?

> Note: Even if try with indexing, there is no much difference in result time.

Thanks

Comment: Index wont make a bit of difference to a query that summarises all the table data - mysql gonna have to access every row anyway, so it will just bypass using an index - using an index actually slows things down in cases like this. You're going to have to post the plan for this query before we have a shot at explaining any performance issue

Comment: Please use explicit column/aliases for Order by; instead of error-prone column number

Comment: Please show the query plan (with and without indexes) and table creation scrips (including indexes if you created any). It would also help to know how may rows in your saleschannel table..

Answer (score 2):

Two approaches to this:

**One approach** is to create [a *covering index*](http://www.unofficialmysqlguide.com/covering-indexes.html) on the columns needed to satisfy your query. The correct index for your query contains these columns in this order: `(SalesChannel, UnitPrice)`.

Why does this help?  For one thing, the index itself contains all data needed to satisfy your query, and nothing else. This means your server does less work.

For another thing, MySQL's indexes are BTREE-organized. That means they're accessible in order. So your query can be satisfied one `SalesChannel` at a time, and MySQL doesn't need an internal temporary table. That's faster.

A **second approach** involves recognizing that `ORDER BY ... LIMIT` is a notorious performance antipattern.  You require MySQL to sort a big mess of data, and then discard most of it.

You could try this:

```
SELECT SUM(UnitPrice) UnitPrice,
       SalesChannel Channel
  FROM samplesalesdata50000
 WHERE SalesChannel IN (
         SELECT SalesChannel 
           FROM samplesalesdata50000
          ORDER BY Channel LIMIT 200 OFFSET 0
       )
 GROUP BY SalesChannel 
 ORDER BY SalesChannel 
 LIMIT 200 OFFSET 0
```

If you have an index on `SalesChannel` (the covering index mentioned above works) this should speed you up a lot, because your aggregate (`GROUP BY`) query need only consider a subset of your table.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem with "ORDER BY 2 ASC". Try this "ORDER BY Channel".

Answer (score 0):

If it was MS SQL Server you would use the `WITH (NOLOCK)`

and the MYSQL equivalent is

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED ;
SELECT SUM(`samplesalesdata50000`.`UnitPrice`) AS `UnitPrice`, `samplesalesdata50000`.`SalesChannel` AS `Channel`
FROM `samplesalesdata50000` AS `samplesalesdata50000`
GROUP BY `samplesalesdata50000`.`SalesChannel`
ORDER BY SalesChannel  ASC
LIMIT 200  OFFSET 0
COMMIT ;
```

Comment: SQL server also accepts `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;`

Answer (score 0):

To improve on OJones's answer, note that

```
SELECT SalesChannel FROM samplesalesdata50000
    ORDER BY SalesChannel LIMIT 200, 1
```

will quickly (assuming the index given) find the end of the desired list.  Then adding this limits the main query to only the rows needed:

```
WHERE SalesChannel < (that-select)
```

There is, however, a problem.  If there are fewer than 200 rows in the table, the subquery will return nothing.

You seem to be setting up for "paginating"?  In that case, a similar technique can be used to find the starting value:

```
WHERE SalesChannel >= ...
  AND SalesChannel  < ...
```

This also avoids using the inefficient `OFFSET`, which has to read, then toss, all the rows being skipped over.  [*More*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination)

But the real solution may be to build and maintain a Summary Table of the data.  It would contain subtotals for each, say, month.  Then run the query against the Summary table -- it might be 10x faster.  [*More*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables)